# What is the highest ordinal that can’t be obtained from Kleene’s O with oracles?

Tags: set-theory, computability, ordinals, turing-machines, oracles

Kleene’s $O$ is a way to use natural numbers as notations for recursive ordinals.  $0$ is a notation for $0$.  If $i$ is a notation for $\alpha$, then $2^i$ is a notation for $\alpha+1$.  And if $\phi_e$ (the $e^{th}$ partial recursive function) is a total recursive function enumerating ordinal notations in strictly increasing order (as ordinals), then $3\cdot 5^e$ is a notation for the least upper bound of the ordinals denoted by the range of $\phi_e$.  The least ordinal which cannot be obtained in this way is the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$.

I’m wondering what happens if you modify the definition of Kleene’s $O$ to allow for oracles.  Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.  As before, let $0$ be a notation for $0$, and if $i$ is a notation for $\alpha$, then $2^i$ is a notation for $\alpha+1$.  But now if $\phi_e^A$ (the the $e^{th}$ partial recursive function with access to $A$ as an oracle) is a total $A$-recursive function enumerating ordinal notations in strictly increasing order (as ordinals), then let $3\cdot 5^e$ be a notation for the least upper bound of the ordinals denoted by the range of $\phi_e$.  Let $O_A$ be the set of all ordinal notations obtained in this way.

My question is, what is the least ordinal which does not have a notation in $O_A$ for any set $A$?  Is it $\omega_1$, or is there a countable ordinal with this property?

Comment: I think similar questions have been posted on Mathoverflow or this site. Unfortunately, I could not find these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Every countable ordinal can be so reached.**

This is easiest to see by first switching from notations to general computable relations. Trivially the set of countable ordinals which have a copy computable relative to some oracle is all of $\omega_1$ - given an (infinite) ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$ just take $A$ to be well-ordering of $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$.

We can then pass from this to notations by relativizing the proof that every computable ordinal is constructive (= has length $\vert e\vert_\mathcal{O}$ for some $e\in\mathcal{O}$), the details of which can be found in [Sacks' book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631) *(I believe he gives the relativization as an exercise)*.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the smallest ordinal that can’t be reached by a given oracle?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It's the analogue of $\omega_1^{CK}$. These ordinals are inherently hard to describe, but here's one thing we can say: the smallest ordinal with no $A$-computable copy is the smallest $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha[A]$ satisfies KP + Infinity. (This is usually denoted "$\omega_1^r$" - but I find that confusing since the same notation is used for what $L[r]$ thinks is $\omega_1$.) [Sacks proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094574/where-is-the-theorem-related-to-the-construction-of-countable-admissible-ordinal) that every admissible ordinal $>\omega$ arises as such.

Comment: What does $L_\alpha[A]$ mean?

Comment: It's level $\alpha$ of the constructible hierarchy relativized to $A$; Devlin's book has a good treatment.

Comment: And what about the reverse problem?  Given a concrete description of a countable ordinal, is there a way to find a “naturally-occurring” oracle that computes it, as opposed to an oracle specially designed from the ordinal itself?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, "naturally-occurring" is an imprecise term, but I'd argue that the answer is **no**: it is after all consistent with ZF + DC that there is no injection of $\omega_1$ into $2^\omega$ (= the set of oracles). So any way of whipping up a "canonical" description of a given countable ordinal has to either not work in general or crucially invoke choice (which pushes back on canonicity). That said, interpreted broadly enough the answer is consistently **yes**: e.g. if under $V=L$ we can take the $L$-least code for the given ordinal $\alpha$ - this is unnatural, but "canonical."

Comment: Well, I don't want a procedure that's guaranteed to work for all countable ordinals or anything.  I just mean, for the handful of non-recursive countable ordinals that humans have actually named and studied, is it possible to find "naturally-occurring" oracles that compute at least some of them?  For instance, is there a simple oracle that computes [my favorite ordinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3224027/71829) $\beta_0$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Per my previous comment, this works (broadly interpreted) for as long as we have "canonical fine structure" - in particular, for any ordinal which is $<\omega_1^L$ (= is countable in $L$) we can look at the "$L$-least code." Similarly, if $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable then the first-order theory of $L_\alpha$ computes a copy of $\alpha$ and is pretty natural. So - as with many of your other questions - one important place to look is the $L$-hierarchy and its fine structural properties.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But at this point we're drifting pretty far from the OP; I'd recommend asking a new question instead of continuing this comment thread.

Comment: OK, I posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427366/71829

Comment: I just posted another folow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427422/71829