# What is the smallest ordinal not computable by using artihmetical truth as an oracle?

Tags: set-theory, computability, ordinals, peano-axioms, oracles

Kleene's $O$ is a way to use natural numbers as notations for recursive ordinals.  I’m wondering what happens if you modify the definition of Kleene’s $O$ to allow for arithmetical truth as an oracle.  Let $T$ be the set of Godel numbers of true statements in the language of first-order arithmetic.  Let $0$ be a notation for $0$, and if $i$ is a notation for $\alpha$, then $2^i$ is a notation for $\alpha+1$. If $\phi_e^T$ (the $e^{th}$ partial recursive function with access to $T$ as an oracle) is a total $T$-recursive function enumerating ordinal notations in strictly increasing order (as ordinals), then let $3\cdot 5^e$ be a notation for the least upper bound of the ordinals denoted by the range of $\phi_e$.  Let $O_T$ be the set of all ordinal notations obtained in this way.

My question is, what is the smallest ordinal that does not have a notation in $O_T$?  I realize that ordinal might be difficult to describe exactly, but can we at least put some upper and lower bounds on how big it is?

Comment: I really recommend reading Sacks' book - many of your questions are directly answered in it, and it's freely and legally available online.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a theorem of Spector that every [hyperarithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory) ordinal is computable (see [Sacks' book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631)). True (first-order) arithmetic is *tiny* in the hyperarithmetic hierarchy, so it doesn't get us any further than $\omega_1^{CK}$.

- In fact, a stronger result is true: $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)=HYP$.

(Incidentally, it's also true that [every computable ordinal is polynomial-time computable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82136/ordinals-and-complexity-classes), so $\omega_1^{CK}$ is the first non-polytime-computable ordinal *and* the first non-hyperarithmetic ordinal. It's a really robust notion!)

---

Note that as usual, it's far simpler to talk about computable ordinals than notations. There are situations where notations are useful, but in my experience more as a *tool* than the initial definition.

Comment: What do you mean by talking about computable ordinals rather than notations?  How do I phrase my question without talking about notations?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan A computable ordinal is an ordinal which has a computable copy: that is, an ordinal $\alpha$ is computable iff *($\alpha$ is finite or)* there is some computable binary relation $R$ on $\omega$ which well-orders $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$. Similarly, a hyperarithmetic ordinal is one with a hyperarithmetic copy, etc. The classic text for this topic is Ash/Knight [Computable structures and the hyperarithmetic hierarchy](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computable-structures-and-the-hyperarithmetical-hierarchy/ash/978-0-444-50072-4) - unfortunately that one's harder to find.

Comment: The fact mentioned in my answer to your other recent question - that "constructive" ordinals (= ordinals with notations) and computable ordinals coincide, and that this relativizes - is the key to switching from notations to general copies. In particular, your question can be rephrased as: "What is the least ordinal with no copy computable from true first-order arithmetic?"

Comment: Cool, Ash/Knight is the textbook of the logic course I'm taking next semester.

Comment: Does truth in the language of first-order set theory in the standard model of $ZFC$ get you anywhere higher than the Church-Kleene ordinal?  Or is "the standard model of $ZFC$" too vague to answer that?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "The standard model of ZFC" is indeed super vague, but regardless of how we interpret it it's massive overkill: *any* well-founded model $M$ of ZFC (or indeed much less) will have $\omega_1^{CK}(Th(M))>\omega_1^{CK}$ by quite a bit. Note that such an $M$ will compute $\mathcal{O}$ correctly ...

Comment: Also, whenever $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable and $\alpha$ is a definable element of $M$ we'll have $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}(Th(M))$. So e.g. $\beta_0<\omega_1^{CK}(Th(M))$, and so forth. Going up to a transitive model of ZFC is really quite a jump. (That said, transitivity is necessary: by the Gandy basis theorem there is an $\omega$-model $M$ of ZFC - or indeed any $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence which is an element of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ - which is low for hyperjump, so that $\omega_1^{CK}(M)=\omega_1^{CK}$.)

Comment: Wait, so then truth in $ZFC$ (whatever that means) will compute $\beta_0$, right?  That's the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: (I think you're referring to your other recent question?) Yeah, but that's **galactic** overshooting, to the point that I didn't even consider it. I can add it if you like though. (It's also rather unfair: in order to make it canonical we need to specify a transitive model of ZFC, and this basically winds up dodging reference to $\beta_0$ by referring to a souped-up version of $\beta_0$, which seems cheating.)

Comment: Yes, please add it.  By the way, what about truth in the language of second-order arithmetic?  Does that buy you anything more than Church-Kleene, and does that get you to $\beta_0$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I believe this was answered in a previous question of yours: the true second-order theory of the naturals is vastly more complicated than hyperarithmetic, or $\beta_0$, or anything of that ilk. (Heck, it's not even set-theoretically absolute without large cardinals!)

Comment: OK great, so then "truth in second-order arithmetic" sounds like a good answer to my other question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Again, though, galactic overshooting (and the fact that without further set-theoretic hypotheses it's not even absolute renders it further bizarre).