# What ordinals are computable using $\Sigma^1_2$ and $\Pi^1_2$ truth?

Tags: set-theory, computability, ordinals, second-order-logic, oracles

The least non-recursive ordinal is $\omega_1^{CK}$, the Church-Kleene ordinal.  But with the benefit of oracles, you can compute more ordinals.  Or at least you can with the benefit of sufficiently powerful oracles; this answer shows that‪ using the set of all truths of first-order‬ arithmetic doesn’t buy you any more ordinals.

But my question is, what ordinals do you get if you use the set of all $\Sigma_2^1$ and $\Pi_2^1$ truths?  That is to say, let $T$ be the set of all Gödel numbers of true $\Sigma_2^1$ and $\Pi_2^1$ statements in the language of second-order arithmetic.  Then what is the least ordinal with no copy computable using $T$ as an oracle?

I realize that ordinal might be difficult to describe exactly, but can we at least put some upper and lower bounds on how big it is?  In any case, the reason I ask is because of the connection to these kinds of truths with Schoenfeld’s Absoluteness Theorem.

Comment: I think that you can get pretty high ordinals, depending on the ordinals of V. For example, assume that there is a transitive model of ZFC. Then, I believe that the least real in $L$ that codes a transitive model $M$ of ZFC is $\Delta^1_2$-definable. In particular $o(M)$ is computable from this oracle. Now, replace ZFC with ZFC + LC, where LC is any [recursive] large cardinal axiom, assuming that there is in V a transitive model for it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $Th_{\Pi^1_2}(\mathbb{N})$ (which I'll call "$X_2$") computes *really really big* ordinals; so big, in fact, that there's a decent argument that their supremum $\omega_1^{CK}(X_2)$ is "fundamentally non-concrete."

*(Below, I'm only thinking about limit ordinals for simplicity. Also note that this is an elaboration of Yair Hayut's comment above.)*

The idea is to use the fact that $L$ has definable Skolem functions; this means that "first-order phenomena" in $L$ can be located relatively easily, namely in a $\Pi^1_2$ way, and so all ordinals corresponding to such will have copies computable from $X_2$. For simplicity, all ordinals are limit ordinals, all theories contain KPi + V=L, and I'll conflate a set $A$ with the corresponding structure $(A; \in\upharpoonright A)$.

- It's worth noting that there's an important subtlety here. [The levels of the arithmetic hierarchy correspond to iterates of the Turing jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem#Post's_theorem_and_corollaries), but the levels of the projective hierarchy **do not** correspond to iterates of the hyperjump. In particular, $\mathcal{O}^\mathcal{O}$ is *galactically* simpler than $X_2$, and $\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{O}^{(n)})$ is just $\omega_{n+1}^{CK}$. (The key point is that $\mathcal{O}^{(n)}\in L_{\omega_{n+1}^{CK}}$.) It's a good exercise to check why the "obvious" proof that $\mathcal{O}^\mathcal{O}\equiv_TX_2$ breaks down *(HINT: think about what you're quantifying over ...)*.

---

First, the setup:

For $A$ a set, let $D(A)$ be the set of definable elements of $A$ and let $M(A)$ be the Mostowski collapse of $A$. The key thing to think about is the map $$A\mapsto M(D(A)).$$ In general $A$ and $M(D(A))$ may have very little to do with each other; however, a couple very nice things happen in case $A=L_\theta$ for some ordinal $\theta$:

- Since $L_\theta$ has definable Skolem functions, we have $D(L_\theta)\preccurlyeq L_\theta$ and so $M(D(L_\theta))\equiv L_\theta$.
- By condensation we have $M(D(L_\theta))=L_{\theta'}$ for some $\theta'\le\theta$, with $\theta'=\theta$ iff $D(L_\theta)=L_\theta$ (that is, iff $L_\theta$ is **pointwise-definable**).

*(In fact, we also know that $M(D(M(D(L_\theta))))=M(D(L_\theta))$ - that is, after applying $M\circ D$ we get something pointwise-definable - but that won't be needed here.)*

---

Now, here's how the above observations lead to a lot of pointwise-definable levels of $L$.

Suppose $T$ is a theory and $L_\theta$ is the least level of $L$ satisfying $T$. Then since $L_{\theta'}$ also satisfies $T$ we must have $\theta'=\theta$ - that is, we must have $L_\theta$ be pointwise-definable.

In particular, $L_{\omega_{17}^{CK}}$ is pointwise-definable: take $T$ to be KPi + V=L + "There are sixteen admissible ordinals." Similarly, $L_{\beta_0}$ are pointwise-definable.

Indeed, it turns out that the set of $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is pointwise-definable is cofinal in $\omega_1^L$ (see [Hamkins/Linetsky/Reitz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4597.pdf)).

---

OK, so what?

Well, if $L_\alpha$ is pointwise-definable, then $Th(L_\alpha)$ computes a copy of $\alpha$ - simply ask $Th(L_\alpha)$ which formulas correspond to ordinals and how they should be ordered. So in particular, if $L_\alpha$ is pointwise-definable and $Th(L_\alpha)\le_TX_2$ then $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}(X_2)$.

So we wrap up with the following observation. For a theory $T$, let $$\alpha_T=\min\{\beta: L_\beta\models T\}$$ (with the convention that $\alpha_T=0$ if no level of $L$ satisfies $T$). Then we have:

> **Theorem**: If $T$ is **computable**, then $Th(L_{\alpha_T})$ is $\Delta^1_2$.

*(Proof: The point is that $L_{\alpha_T}$ is in fact the unique level of $L$ satisfying $T$ + "$T$ has no transitive models." So we have $L_{\alpha_T}\models\varphi$ iff every well-founded model of $T$ + "$T$ has no well-founded models" satisfies $\varphi$ iff there is some well-founded model of $T$ + "$T$ has no well-founded models" which satisfies $\varphi$, and these last two clauses are $\Pi^1_2$ and $\Sigma^1_2$ respectively.)*

Putting this all together, we get $\alpha_T<\omega_1^{CK}(X_2)$ for every computable theory $T$. For example, $\beta_0<\omega_1^{CK}(X_2)$ (take $T=ZFC -P + V=L$). This more-or-less precludes any "from-below" characterization of $\omega_1^{CK}(X_2)$; we're left with characterizations in terms of reflection principles and their ilk, which can be a bit tautological. So ultimately I'd take this as an argument that this ordinal is simply too huge to be well-described.