# What is the Turing degree of truth in the second-order theory of real numbers?

Tags: logic, computability, second-order-logic, reverse-math

Let $X$ be the set of Godel numbers of sentences in the second-order language of ordered fields which are true in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then my question is, what is the Turing degree of $X$?

In particular, how does it compare to the Turing degree of truth in second-order arithmetic?  One datapoint is that the second-order arithmetic is interpretable in the second-order theory of real numbers.  Another datapoint is second-order theory of real numbers is interpretable in second-order arithmetic with third-order parameters.  Yet another datapoint is that both second-order arithmetic and the second-order theory of real numbers are categorical theories.  I'm not sure whether these facts imply that the Turing degree of $X$ is the same as the Turing degree of truth in second-order arithmetic, but it least seems intuitively plausible that the two Turing degrees are of the same "order of magnitude".

Comment: Unrelated but amusing: even the monadic second-order theory of $(\mathbb{R};<)$ is [consistently undecidable](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971037).

Comment: "second-order theory of real numbers is interpretable in second-order arithmetic with third-order parameters." I don't think I buy that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm probably not phrasing it right, but I was trying to paraphrase the comment by François Dorais on my question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366294/what-subsystem-of-third-order-arithmetic-proves-the-real-numbers-are-dedekind-co#comment925062_366294

Comment: All Francois is talking about there is how to prove completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ in an appropriate sense. That doesn't give you an interpretation of the whole second-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber By the way, do we know the Turing degree of the true monadic second-order theory of $(\mathbb{R};<)$, assuming CH?

Comment: I don't think so - at a glance, all the linked paper shows is that under $\mathsf{CH}$ it's at least ${\bf 0'}$ (Theorem $7.11$ essentially). But that paper isn't maximally clear.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It turns out we can say much more than that, I just posted a MathOverflow question containing more info: https://mathoverflow.net/q/385530/5017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is second-order-definable in $\mathbb{R}$, the true second-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$ is basically the same as (= computably isomorphic to) true third-order arithmetic. And the gap between true *third-order* arithmetic and true *second-order* arithmetic is gigantic. For example, true second-order arithmetic (construed as a set of natural numbers via Godelization) is definable over $\mathbb{N}$ by a single third-order formula.

Incidentally, there's a methodological point here: what would a "satisfying description" of the relevant Turing degree consist of? For sets of this complexity we're way beyond the point of well-behaved degree constructions, and I think the best we can hope for is descriptions of the form "The Turing degree of the $\mathfrak{L}$-theory of $\mathcal{M}$" for some natural logic $\mathfrak{L}$ and natural structure $\mathcal{M}$. It's often convenient to look for descriptions of this form with $\mathcal{M}$ a nice transitive set, so in this case "The third-order theory of $L_\omega$" would be my suggestion of an answer.

(This point about "naming" Turing degrees is similar to the point about "naming" large ordinals I made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437558/28111), and I believe in a couple other related answers as well. In each case, unless one has a specific form of description in mind, I think the initial description is actually optimal-ish.)

Comment: Why does the second-order definability of N in R imply that the true second-order theory of real numbers is the same as true third-order arithmetic?  How can you talk about "for all sets of sets of natural numbers" and "there exists a set of sets of natural numbers" in the second-order language of ordered fields?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Because once you have $\mathbb{N}$ you can code subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ by individual reals. So that reduces $(n+1)$th-order questions about $\mathbb{N}$ to $n$th-order questions about $\mathbb{R}$, as long as $n\ge 2$.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense.