# Alpha recursion - Constructible universe and Analytical hierarchy

Tags: computability, ordinals, foundations, descriptive-set-theory, oracles

[Alpha recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_recursion_theory) and [Constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) are very intertwined, because  the first is based on the concept of [admissible ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal) $\alpha$ which is defined as an ordinal such that $L_\alpha$ - a set of the Constructible universe- is a model of [Kripke-Platek set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory).

The first two admissible ordinals are $\omega$ and [$\omega_1^{\mathsf{CK}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonrecursive_ordinal).

$L_{\omega_{1}^{\mathsf{CK}}} \cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $ is the set of ${\displaystyle \omega _{1}^{\mathsf{CK}}}$-recursive subsets of $\omega$  which are exactly the
$\Delta _{1}^{1}$ (a.k.a. [hyperarithmetical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory)) subsets of $\omega$.

By taking an oracle for $\omega_{1}^{\mathsf{CK}}$ we can define $\omega_{2}^{\mathsf{CK}}= \omega_{1}^{\mathsf{CK}}[\omega_{1}^{\mathsf{CK}}]$  and we can extend this in general to $\omega_{n}^{\mathsf{CK}}$.
Beyond this construction there are recursive Inaccessible  ordinals and further on recursive Mahlo ordinals and then progressively bigger countable admissible ordinals.
The supremum of countable admissible ordinals is $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal which is also admissible.

My question is where do  the sets of the constructible universe corresponding to the countable admissible ordinals beyond   $\omega_{1}^{\mathsf{CK}} $ such as $L_{\omega_{2}^{\mathsf{CK}}}\cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $, $L_{\omega_{n}^{\mathsf{CK}}}\cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $,... ,$L_{I}\cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $, $L_{M}\cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $... belong in the Analytical hierarchy?
How far up do you go in the Analytical hierarchy with $L_\alpha \cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega)$ when $\alpha$ approaches $\omega_1$ , and what about the sets of $L_{\omega_1}\cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $, where do they belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a correction: you're conflation $L_\alpha$ with $L_\alpha\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. E.g. $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is not the set of hyperarithmetic reals, but $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is.

Second, for simplicity let's assume $\mathsf{V=L}$. This means that $L_{\omega_1}$ contains every real, so the analytic hierarchy stops well before $L_{\omega_1}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$.

OK, what about smaller admissible ordinals - say, the $\omega_n^{CK}$s for finite $n$ - and the first couple levels of the analytical hierarchy? Well, already in $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}$ we have Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$, and so $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ contains every $\Pi^1_1$ real and every $\Sigma^1_1$ real. But in fact those reals already showed up in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}+1}$, so $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is *much bigger* than (the Boolean algebra generated by) the $\Sigma^1_1$ and $\Pi^1_1$ sets. The question is: does it reach as high as $\Delta^1_2$?

The answer, perhaps surprisingly, is **no**. The gulf between the first two levels of the analytical hierarchy is gigantic. The key tool here is the canonical well-ordering of $L$. For any first-order sentence $\sigma$, let $r_\sigma$ be the $\le_L$-least real coding a level of $L$ satisfying $\sigma$; this is a $\Delta^1_2$ real, and consequently all the "easily-describable" levels of the $L$-hierarchy will fall short of containing all the $\Delta^1_2$ reals. For example, let $\theta$ be the first recursively Mahlo ordinal; then letting $\sigma$ be the sentence such that the $L$-levels satisfying $\sigma$ are exactly those with recursively Mahlo index we get that $r_\sigma$ is a $\Delta^1_2$ real not in $L_\theta$ (this last bit uses the fact that if $r_\sigma$ were in $L_\theta$, then $L_\theta$ would contain a real coding $L_\theta$ itself, which via the [pointwise-definability](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) of $L_\theta$ would contradict [Tarski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)).

Hinman's book [**Recursion-theoretic hierarchies**](https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/Recursion-Theoretic-Hierarchies/toc/pl/1235415519) contains a lot of useful information about the $\Delta^1_2$ reals and just how complicated they can be. In particular, I recommend taking a look at Corollary V.4.11, which in a precise sense says that the $\Delta^1_2$ sets can't be "built from below" in as simple a way as the hyperarithmetic sets. [This old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437558/28111) is also relevant for getting a sense of just how powerful the second level of the analytical (also called projective) hierarchy is.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I will make a correction. About the answer you say that for all countable admissible $\alpha$ that we have been able to define  so far (like recursive Mahlo  as you mention)  $L_\alpha \cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $ is a proper subset of $\Delta^1_2$ sets. But what can we say about the non easily definable countable admissible ordinals and what about $ L_{\omega_1} \cap  \mathcal{P} (\omega) $?

Comment: @holmes Well, it's consistent that $L_{\omega_1}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)=\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, as I said in my answer (second paragraph). Meanwhile, "what can we say about the non easily definable countable admissible ordinals" is too vague a question for me to address, to be honest. Certainly there is some smallest $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ contains every $\Delta^1_2$ real, and this $\alpha$ is countable; but I see no reason to expect it to have a nicer definition than the first half of this sentence.

Comment: Yes I see it now, my ADHD sometimes comes in to my way. Do we use any hierarchy beyond the analytical hierarchy.

Comment: @holmes Yes, we can go further, and inner model theorists often do. However, there's already so much going on at the low levels of the analytical hierarchy (e.g. even with respect to inner model theory, the "simple" inner models all contain only $\Delta^1_3$ reals assuming large cardinals exist) that this is a bit of a niche topic.

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be least such that $L_\sigma$ is a $\Sigma_1$-elementary substructure of $L$. It is known that a real is $\Delta^1_2$ iff it is $\Delta_1$-definable on $L_\sigma$ (page 6 of Madore's "[A Zoo of Ordinals](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf)"), and this is the least level with this property, as each previous level is missing some real from $L_\sigma$ (theorem 6.14 in Marek and Srebrny's "Gaps in the Constructible Universe", plus that there is no $\sigma$-stable $\alpha<\sigma$). So perhaps $\sigma+1$ is the least $\alpha$ where all $\Delta^1_2$ reals are in $L_\alpha$